# Keyboard getting displayed sometimes in textfield picker view in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have a textfield which when tapped displays a `UIPickerView`. I add it as `inputView` of the text field. Sometimes when I tap the textfield, it displays keyboard instead of the picker view. I have added a custom class that subclasses `UITextField` as well.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // ...
    monthTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(monthTextFieldDidTap), for: UIControl.Event.touchDown)
}


@objc func monthTextFieldDidTap(textField: UITextField) {
    activePickerType = PickerType.month
    viewDatePicker(textField)
}

@objc func yearTextFieldDidTap(textField: UITextField) {
    activePickerType = PickerType.year
    viewDatePicker(textField)
}

func viewDatePicker(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.datePicker = UIPickerView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.navigationController!.view.frame.size.width, height: 216))
    self.datePicker.delegate = self
    self.datePicker.dataSource = self
    textField.inputView = self.datePicker
    // ...
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if (textField == monthTextField) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

The custom subclass of `UITextField`:

```
class PickerTextField: UITextField {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func caretRect(for position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect.zero
    }

    func selectionRects(for range: UITextRange) -> [Any] {
        return []
    }

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        UIMenuController.shared.isMenuVisible = false
        self.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
}
```

How make sure that keyboard does not get displayed when tapped on the `UITextField` and always display the `UIPickerView`?

Comment: Set inputView for all textfields in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place these lines in viewDidLoad instead of monthTextFieldDidTap

```
self.datePicker = UIPickerView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.navigationController!.view.frame.size.width, height: 216))
self.datePicker.delegate = self
self.datePicker.dataSource = self
monthTextField.inputView = self.datePicker



func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
if (textField == monthTextField) {
    activePickerType = PickerType.month
    viewDatePicker(textField)

}
return true
```

}

Comment: I have three textfields `monthTextField`, `yearTextField`, `stateTextField`. So this is making the other `UIPickerView` elements to not display.

Comment: assign delegate to your textfields and in shouldBeginEditing check for the textField and call these lines their instead.

activePickerType = PickerType.year
    viewDatePicker(textField)

Comment: If I don't give `textField.inputView = pickerView` and I tap on the second textfield, I am getting `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller:<UICompatibilityInputViewController: 0x10ea104a0> should have parent view controller:<App.CalendarViewController: 0x10695c200> but requested parent is:<UIInputWindowController: 0x106a44a00>'` error.

Comment: It works fine. I assigned wrong control in the `textField.inputView`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add self.view.endEditing() line in monthTextFieldDidTap(textField: UITextField) function as below:

```
@objc func monthTextFieldDidTap(textField: UITextField) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    monthTextField.tintColor = UIColor.clear    //optional to use. It just removes cursor blinking on picker Textfield
    self.datePicker = UIPickerView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.navigationController!.view.frame.size.width, height: 216))
    self.datePicker.delegate = self
    self.datePicker.dataSource = self
    textField.inputView = self.datePicker
    // ...
}
```

Comment: When I am checking it's not showing keyboard in my case. Is there anything else which you didn't mention in your question and you are using?

Comment: It works for the above answer. Please check the updated code. I shows keyboard mostly when tapping on the textfield value for the first time or so.

Comment: It works for the above answer. Please check the updated code. I shows keyboard mostly when tapping on the textfield value for the first time or so.